# How can I adjust the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to write a report in LaTeX. First, I tried to align the table of contents to the left. Then I changed my mind but I couldn't restore. I would like to make some distance between the Sections and Subsections such as 4cm (not aling to left).  I would like to change  table of contents as below figure.

[image]

Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=25mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\PassOptionsToPackage{version=3}{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=t`enter code here`rue,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1, breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false] {hyperref}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}


\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\providecolor{lyxadded}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\providecolor{lyxdeleted}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\texorpdfstring{\color{lyxadded}{}}{}#3}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]{{\texorpdfstring{\color{lyxdeleted}\sout{#3}}{}}}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{0.9em}
\usepackage{feyn}

 \usepackage[center]{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
   {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries
\centering} {\MakeUppercase \thechapter.}{1pt}{\MakeUppercase}
 \titleformat{\section}
   {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection .}{1pt}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
   {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection .}{1pt}{}
     \titleformat{\subsubsection}
   {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection .}{1pt}{}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
 \titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
 \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\hfil\textbf}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{5}
\def\contentsname{CONTENTS}


\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{25em} 
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{25em} 
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.1}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.0em}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.7em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.4em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{2.8em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnum}{.}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\hfil\textbf}
\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}



\chapter{A}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is far away from minimal and does not compile for me. Please reduce as much as you can. If you delete package by package, line by line, you will find the culprit part quickly.

Comment: Some notes: Do not load `color` as you load the newer `xcolor`. Do not load packages twice (e.g. `caption`, `amsmath`, `natbib`...). Load `babel` with a language (e.g. `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. Use `siunitx` and not `units`. Load `hyperref` last (valid for most cases). `report` does not define a `\mainmatter`. `\makeatletter\makeatother` is just needed around parts with @. Do not surround too much with it. And in general. Do not load packages and options which you do not use and do not know. If they are missing later, you can add them again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LaRiFaRi.  By the way, Do you know the exact code for arranging the distance in table of contents ?

Comment: Please clarify what you want and minimize your code. The title of "Contents" can be restored to be in the middle by deleting `\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}`.

Comment: I try to explain what I want by figure. I think there is some misunderstanding. I tried to reduce the package as your direction @LaRiFaRi

Comment: This is still not minimal. Not even close. I did now, what I recommended you to do and deleted line by line. The problem is the `\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}`. Remove the option and you are good to continue, I hope.

Comment: When I remove \usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle} and change \setlength{\cftsecindent}{2em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3em} 
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{4em}  I guess it works ! Thanks for all your help @LaRiFaRi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `tocfullflat` option from the package `tocstyle`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=25mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill} % if you want this title centred, this has to go away
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocstyle} % removed the flat toc option here
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries
    \centering} {\MakeUppercase \thechapter.}{1pt}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection .}{1pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection .}{1pt}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}
%{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection .}{1pt}{} % not used here
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
%\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0.3ex plus .2ex} % not used here

\begin{document}    
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\hfil\textbf}
    \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{5}
    \def\contentsname{CONTENTS} 

    \setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}  
    \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{25em} 
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}    

    \chapter{A}
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]